# How to Unselect (Un-Highlight) buttons in the same IBAction

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, switch-statement, ibaction

I'm using 3 UIbuttons in my projects these 3 buttons share the same IBAction and I used Switch controller Using the tags the Sender gives to highlight the sender button using `Sender.isSelected = True`.

What I would like to do is instead of calling the other 2 buttons to unselect them in each case, I want to know if there is a way to unselect the other buttons sharing the same IBAction without calling the other buttons in each case.

my current code:

```
@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) { 

        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            tenPctButton.isSelected = false
            twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
            sender.isSelected = true

        case 10:
            zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
            twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
            sender.isSelected = true

        case 20:
            tenPctButton.isSelected = false
            zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
            sender.isSelected = true
     }
}
```

Comment: you can use the view loop and fetch all sub-element and check it with your button.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe it helps you

```
  for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIButton {
             //here you can check your buttons tag and perform opration
        }
    }
```